# AWS Security group for restricting inbound traffic from private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc

I have a load balancer with public IP, which delegates calls to two EC2 web servers on a *private* subnet in AWS VPC. For redundancy reasons, each on a separate private subnet. Let them be denoted as *A1*, *A2*.
These web servers are required to pass calls to another EC2 instance. Let it be denoted as *B*.
I want it to have incoming connections only from *A1*, *A2*.
However, For internal reasons, I do not want to duplicate this EC2 instance for every private subnet. Therefore, my suggested solution is to restrict *B*'s security group to have inbound rule to accept connections only from *A1*, *A2*.

How can I restrict inbound traffic of an EC2 instance outside of my private subnets, so it will accept traffic only from instances from within the private subnets?

I believe I should look for the public IP of the internet gateways of these private subnets, however it seems that such is associated only with a public subnet.

Answer (score 4):

Instances can have multiple security groups.
Security groups can reference other security groups as source.
Security groups are linked to the VPC level.

In this case a solution can be:

- A1, A2 in the same security group A.
- B having a different security group holding an inbound rule that allows connections from security group A.

Comment: My question is more about how to I find the public IP to restrict traffic from, so it will enable traffic only from the private subnet instances (which naturally do not have a public IP).

Comment: @oleiba And hargut explained that's unnecessary since you can allow from a security group rather than an IP, which solves your stated problem.